# Manipulating a vector of one class inside of 2 functions of another class

Tags: c++, class, templates

This seems to very very complicated,  I tried a lot to solve it, but when I resize a private member inside the template/class, i.e., when I call Operator::InitExtVector, I resize intVect through its address, and when I show/call Operator::ShowExtVector its size is 0 again, which should not be happening. Why the vector information is lost?

I have a template/class, Base.H:

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector <unsigned long int >  varVect1D_ul;

<template <typename PS>
class Base{
private:
   PS bla;
   varVect1D_ul intVect;    

public:
      varVect1D_ul* dataVect(){return &intVect}
}
```

some operations are done within the Operator class, normal one no template,Operator.H:

```
 class Operator{
   public:
     .....
   private:

     void InitExtVector(std::vector <Base<float> > BaseVect){ 
             varVect1D_ul *pVect;

             for(i=0...BaseVect.size()){
                 pVect=dataVect();
                 pVect->resize(10);
              }              
        } // end InitExtVector

    void ShowExtVector(std::vector <Base<float> > BaseVect){
             varVect1D_ul *pVect;

             for(i=0...BaseVect.size()){
                 pVect=BaseVect[i].dataVect();
                 cout<<pVect->size();
              } 
    }//end  ShowExtVector  

  };  //end class
```

, and client code looks like
 someOperations.C:

```
  #include "Base.H"
  #include "Operator.H"


  foo(){

   std::vector <Base<float> >  BaseVect(2);
    //do some initization of BseVect;

   Operator *ObjOper= new Operator;    

   ObjOper->InitExtVector(BaseVect);
   ObjOper-> ShowExtVector(BaseVect);



  }
```

All syntax is Ok , the addresses of pVect inside InitExtVect and ShowExtVector are the same

Any help will be gladly appreciated

Regard

JORR

Comment: I dispute that all syntax is OK, since you say `<template <typename PS> class ...`. Anyway, what is it you are really trying to do? Perhaps there's a ready-made data structure somewhere that will do the job.

Comment: -1 not real code. "for(i=0...BaseVect.size())" is not valid C++.

Comment: -1 not real code, syntax is **not** `okay`: "foo()" is not a valid function signature, class declarations must end with a semicolon.

Comment: why do you `pVect->resize(10);` each time in that iteration? `resize()` does not make the `vector` bigger by the amount you tell, but it resizes to that value, i.e. you are keeping it at size 10 in that loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to take your vectors in by reference:

```
void InitExtVector(std::vector <Base<float> > & BaseVect);
void ShowExtVector(std::vector <Base<float> > & BaseVect);
```

Also, did you mean this in InitExtVector:

```
for(i=0 ; i < BaseVect.size() ; ++i){
    pVect=BaseVect[i].dataVect();
    pVect->resize(10);
}
```

Comment: Ok very simple I didn't see it, you understood what I meant. Not like the other 3 guys.  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @rive: The other 3 had very good points though.  Many times people post code that they claim is in a language but its not.  While we would like to trust you when you say the syntax is OK, knowing nothing about you its difficult to do.  The syntax problem could have easily been the problem for someone else.  For that reason, its generally helpful to assume we know nothing about you and be explicit about everything.  Even something as simple as `public: ...` could be your problem and we can't know that for sure unless we see what `...` is.  The point being, try to be more explicit next time.